# Cannot update custom product attribute values

Tags: attributes, custom-attributes

I am new to Magento and I am trying to configure search on basis of custom attibutes value. While working on it I encountered a very strange issue.

Whenever I am trying to update the value of a custom attribute from Product Information > Specification Tab It is not getting updated. It happens for all the products where attribute field type is Text Input. I can change values for dropdown fields.

Can anyone please suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Custom options are used to configure ordered product somehow. For example if you sell rings, and you allow to put some engrawing on them, you can use a custom option of type text, and it looks like this:

[image]

If you want to put some parameters in Specification tab, you need to create them in Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes.

Then add them to Attribute Set that is set for your product (e.g. `Computer` is the name of attribute set I want to edit):

[image]

Edit proper attribute set in Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets to add new attributes.

Now you can fill these new attributes by editing your product.

Take a look also at this tutorial http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html